# Python, how to compare different files

Tags: python

I am trying to make a login GUI for python. I already made a register function that saves the username and passwords into 2 different files. Right now, I have it set so that each line of both files correspond with each other. Now I need to read both files for a login.

```
with open("Users.txt", "r") as user_file:
   with open("Passwords.txt", "r") as pass_file:
   compare = set(user_file).intersection(pass_file)
```

Comment: what's your file data?

Comment: Saving the data in different files is crazy. This seems to be a recurring homework assignment, maybe tell us which course you are taking so others can avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> each line of both files correspond with each other
> ```

You’re not looking for a set. You’re looking for a dict.

*(assuming your files data is separated by newlines)*

```
logins = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in zip(user_file, pass_file)}
```

Then I’m assuming you’re comparing if a given password matches the one stored, use:

```
if pass_attempt == logins[username]:
    #Correct
else:
    #fail
```

Answer (score 0):

One login scheme using User and Password files

```
def check_login(user_name, password):
  " Checks if user_name and password are in their corresponding files "
  with open("Users.txt", "r") as user_file,  open("Passwords.txt", "r") as pass_file:
    for user, passwd in zip(user_file, pass_file):
      # Check each line in corresponding file for match
      if user.rstrip() == user_name and passwd.rstrip() == password:
        return True
    else:
      return False

print(check_login('daffy', 'duck')) # True
print(check_login('daffy', 'ducky')) # False
print(check_login('oliver', 'twist')) # True
print(check_login('oliver', 'duck'))  #File
```

**Input Files**

*Users.txt*

```
daffy
micky
donold
oliver
minnie
```

*Passwords.txt*

```
duck
mouse
duck
twist
mouse
```